# Mehrzahl von Gut

Tags: grammatical-number

In der deutschen Sprache gibt es unterschiedliche Bedeutungen für das 
Substantiv "Gut".

Ich meine folgendes Gut: In einem Staat ist zum Beispiel Rechtssicherheit oder
Meinungsfreiheit ein "hohes Gut".

Wenn man aber von diesem Thema in der Mehrzahl spricht, dann wird es für mich schwierig. Sagt man dann zum Beispiel: "Dies sind wichtige Güter"? Wohl kaum.

Das hört sich dann eher so an wie die Güter im Güterverkehr.

Welche Lösungen fallen euch denn ein.

Vielen Dank im Voraus

Comment: Die *Güter* im Warenverkehr sind dasselbe Ding wie das "hohe *Gut* der Meinungsfreiheit"

Comment: Dein sensibles Gehör wird sich an den Plural _»Güter«_ gewöhnen müssen, es gibt keine Alternative. Da man dies unschwer nachschlagen kann, wird deine Frage (sofern sie so bleibt, wie sie ist) wohl geschlossen.

Answer (score 8):

Das Wort *Gut* hat zwar mehrere Bedeutungen, aber - wie die meisten Substantive - nur eine Pluralform.

Die von dir gemeinte Bedeutung ist die dritte in dieser Liste:

1. Gut = Besitz, Eigentum

   > Die Aufteilung der **Güter** im Zuge einer Scheidung ist schwierig.
2. Gut = landwirtschaftliches Anwesen

   > Die **Güter** Sonnbichl und Ehrenwald gehören beide der Kirche.
3. Gut = etwas von Wert

   > Rechtssicherheit und Meinungsfreiheit sind hohe **Güter** in einer Demokratie.
4. Gut = Tauwerk bei Segelschiffen

   > Zu den stehenden **Gütern** von Segelschiffen gehören Stage, Wanten und Pardunen.
5. Gut = Versandware

   > Sperrige **Güter** werden per Bahn transportiert.

Comment: Wobei es auch prominente Gegenbeispiele gibt: Mütter/Muttern, Bänke/Banken, Sträuße/Straußen

Comment: Genau deshalb schrieb ich ja auch nicht »wie *alle* Substantive«, sondern »wie *die meisten* Substantive«. Denn ich glaube, es gibt kaum mehr als 15 oder 20 Ausnahmen, bei grob geschätzt 250.000 bis 300.000 Substantiven.